# Shortcut for jumping from one method to another method in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I have a class which consist of somany methods, I want to move from one method to another. Is there any shortcut for that ? I am using `Eclipse(INDIGO)`.

```
--> void method1(){

    }
--> void method2(){

    }   
       .
       .
       .

--> void methodn(){

    }
```

I need to go like above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Ctrl + Shift + Cursor Up/Down`.

Comment: Also, F3 will jump to a method/class implementation if it's selected.  Doesn't work well when there is an interface, though.

Comment: @CodeChimp If there is an interface method hold `ctrl` and put the mouse pointer over the method. A popup will show you the option **Open Implementation**. If there is more than one implementation you will get a selection tree equal to the type hierarchy.

Comment: You just made my day!

Comment: @CodeChimp You're welcome. I recommend to read 'Help -> Welcome -> What's New -> Java development tools' on every eclipse release. The 'Welcome' page is the page that is often just closed, but it contains the most interesting information. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Outline view: Window/Show View/Outline